# How to customize the windows AAD Login screen in windows store 8.1 app using C# and xaml?

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a windows store 8.1 app using C# and xaml. I'm authenticating the user with Windows Azure Active directory sign on. When i connect to the service, by default log in screen will look like below.
[image]

But i want to display it like the below, somebody has done the customization like below, how to do this?

[image]

How can i customize the screen like this?

Any help on this please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The customization shown in your screenshot cannot be achieved on the azure ad pages. In case in which your tenant is federated, you can customize the page displayed by ADFS.